# Bash script not killing all PIDs in specified file or allowing partial names for input

Tags: bash, kill

Right now, my bash script works for 1 PID processes and I must use an exact process name for input. It will not accept `*firefox*' for example. Also, I run a bash script that opens multiple`rsync` processes, and I would like this script to kill all of those processes. But, this script only works on processes with 1 PID.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

    createProcfile() {

    ps -eLf | grep -f process.tmp | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2,$10}' | sort -u | egrep -o '[0-9]{4,}' > pid.tmp

#   pgrep "$(cat process.tmp)" > pid.tmp

    }

    PIDFile=pid.tmp

    echo "Enter a process name"
    read -r process
    echo "$process" > process.tmp

#   node_process_id=$(pidof "$process")
    node_process_id=$(ps -eLf | grep $process | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2,$10}' | sort -u | egrep -o '[0-9]{4,}')
    if [[ -z "$node_process_id" ]]; then
            echo "Please enter a valid process."
        rm process.tmp
        exit 0
    fi

    ps -eLf | grep $process | awk '{print $2,$10}' | sort -u | grep -v 'grep'
#   pgrep "$(cat process.tmp)"

    echo "Would you like to kill this process(es)? (y/n)"
    read -r answer

    if [[ "$answer" == y ]]; then

        createProcfile
        pkill -F "$PIDFile"
        rm "$PIDFile"
        sleep 1
        createProcfile

        node_process_id=$(pidof "$process")
        if [[ -z $node_process_id ]]; then
                echo "Process terminated successfully."
            rm process.tmp
            exit 0
        else
            echo "Process not terminated. Kill process manually."
            ps -eLf | grep $process | awk '{print $2,$10}' | sort -u | grep -v 'grep'
#           pgrep "$(cat process.tmp)"
            rm "$PIDFile"
            rm process.tmp
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
```

I edited the script. Thanks to your comments, it works now and does the following:

1. Make script accept partial name as input
2. Kill more than 1 PID

Thank you!

Comment: why not simply use `pkill` instead?

Comment: Yes! @iruvar Thank you! Please answer the question so I can give you points.

Answer (score 0):

```
 It will not accept *firefox*
```

Use killall command. Example :

```
killall -r "process.*"
```

This will kill all the processes whose names contain *process* in the beginning followed by *any stuff*.

The [[ manual ]](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) says :

> `-r, --regexp`
>    Interpret  process  name  pattern as an extended regular  expression.

**Sidenote:**

Note that we have to double quote the regular expression to prevent file globbing.
 (Thanks [@broslow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076724/broslow) for reminding this stuff).

Comment: Still should be quoted or escaped

Comment: I believed it need not be.

Comment: `killall` will never see `*` if there is any file matching `process.*` in your current directory

Comment: @BroSlow : Brilliant and thankyou :) Edited.

Answer (score 0):

[pkill](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pkill.htm) exists to solve your problem. It accepts a pattern to match against the process name, or the entire command line if `-f` is specified.

Comment: The part of the script that I need to accept a partial name should not also kill the process. So, I can't use that. I edited my script to show you what I did to fix it or to use as a 'work-around'